# In Halo 3 how high is the ''shield'' from Requiem's Surface and where does the sunlight come from?

Tags: halo

I've never actually played any of the Halo games so if these questions were already answered please forgive me.

Anyway, although I've never played Halo I have always enjoyed the Forerunner Structures. As a sci-fi architecture nerd, Forerunner Structures are simply among the coolest alien structures in fiction, if not THE coolest. My favorite Forerunner Structure aside from Installation 00 is the ''Shield Worlds''. I am personally amazed that no one ever had a similar sci-fi idea prior to Bungie. Anyway, I am curious as to how they function.

If I am correct, Shield Worlds are planets with a massive shield around them no?

If so, how high from the surface is the ''shield'' portion of a planet and where does the sunlight on planets like Requiem come from if the shield is in place? Surely such a structure would effectively block out the sunlight if it encases the entire planet, right?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  According to [Halopedia](https://www.halopedia.org/Shield_world) they contain internal light sources.  It doesn't specify if they are fixstars or rollstars or a combination.